Well-definedness and spectrum of $(1 + T)^{-1}T$ for a unbounded and self-adjoint operator $T$
Let $T: D(T) \to H$ be a densely defined, closed, unbounded and self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$. We know that the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of $T$ must be real, let us assume that the spectrum is strictly positive.
Would it be correct to say that the resolvent operator $(1 + T)^{-1}$ exists and is bounded since $-1$ is not in the spectrum of $T$ and since $(1 + T)^{-1}$ must be self-adjoint too and commutes with $T$, the operator $(1 + T)^{-1}T$ is self-adjoint as well?
And is there a possibility to express the spectrum of $(1 + T)^{-1}T$ by the spectrum of $T$? Moreover it is known that $(1 + T)^{-1}T$ is a bounded operator. (I thought of a spectral mapping theorem and an unbounded functional calculus.)
Thanks for help in advance!

Your thoughts are good.

Because of the definition of the resolvent set, $(1+T)^{-1}$ exists and is a bounded operator. If the spectrum of $T$ is strictly positive, then the functions $f,g:\sigma(T)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t}$ and $g(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}$ are both real-valued, bounded and continuous. It follows from the functional calculus theorem that $f(T),g(T)$ are bounded extensions of the densely defined operators $(1+T)^{-1}T$ and $(1+T)^{-1}$, proving that both $(1+T)^{-1}T$ and $(1+T)^{-1}$ are symmetric and can be extended to self-adjoint bounded operators. Note that these operators are then essentially self-adjoints, since they are bounded in a dense domain and because of the BLT theorem their only possible bounded extension correspond also to the closure of their graphs.
Finally, because of the spectral theorem and the continuity of $f$ one can compute the spectrum of $f(T)$ by
$$ \sigma(f(T))=f(\sigma(T))=\left\{\left.\frac{t}{1+t}\;\right|\; t\in\sigma(T)\right\}.$$

Thanks! Could you maybe recommend a reference for the functional calculus theorem you used and the spectrum theorem?

The assertion that $f(T) = (1+T)^{-1} T $ is wrong. What is true however is that $(1+T)^{-1} T \subset f(T)$ (they agree on the domain of $T$). In fact $f(T)$ is a bounded and everywhere defined operator, because $f$ is bounded on the spectrum (your last point about the BLT is also pointless as a consequence).

The boundedness would also follow from $(1+T)^{-1}T = 1 -(1+T)^{-1} .$

@jd27: So one can conclude that $\sigma((1+T)^{-1}T) \subset \sigma(f(T)) $ ?

@kumquat I dont think so, i dont even think that $(1+T)^{-1} T$ is necessarily a closed operator.

@jd27 is right and I just changed the answer accordingly. The main difference with my past answer yields in what is in my opinion a technicality, which is making a difference between an operator and its closure and unique bounded extension.

Regarding a nice reference I remember studying these theorems from both Teschl's book "Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics" and Reed and Simon's classic book "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I: Functional Analysis".

Ok, if got this right:
$(1+T)^{-1}T$ is well-defined and bounded on $D(T)$ but not necessarily closed on $D(T).$ But we can (uniquely) extend the operator $(1+T)^{-1}T$ to the whole space $H.$ The extension is closed, bounded, self-adjoint and has well-defined spectrum. And satisfies the spectral mapping theorem. Is that correct?

That is exactly correct :)
